# Check user id is found or not in varchar field (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

How to check userid is available in varchar field or not in sql query

> My table 'tb_feeds'

[image]

I want to set logic as PHP in mysql query like

```
// Same Logic i want in Mysql
$a = 'How are you?';
if (strpos($a, 'are') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

> I want

```
$user_id = '1';

// What i write this query in proper SQL way
SELECT * FROM tb_feeds WHERE feed_display_user_id contains $user_id
```

Comment: You should fix the data model so you are not storing lists of ids in a character field.

Comment: Just don't! normalize your data properly

Comment: You can't, if you search for user ID 1 anything with a 1 in it would match (10,11,12,21,41,100 etc)

Comment: but how i manage this data in one field @GordonLinoff

Comment: @BhavinSasapra - Trying to manage it in one field is incredibly bad design, and very slow and inefficient; it's far better to normalize your data tables properly... if you _absolutely_ have to do it (and the only halfway legitimate reason is a legacy codebase), then use MySQL's [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.... but it will be slow, and requires a lot of additional code to maintain the list

Comment: many thanks @MarkBaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Get This Solution but this is part time solution use another data model for better output.

```
$user_id = '1';

"SELECT * FROM `tb_feeds` WHERE FIND_IN_SET($user_id, feed_display_user_id)"
```